# unable to upload files using php?

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I am unable to upload the files using php.
I am using a common array for a control as media[] here,and then using for loop I am uploading.
here is my code so far:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="gallery.php">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Select File</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="input-file uniform_on" id="media[]" name="media[]" type="file">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Select File</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="input-file uniform_on" id="media[]" name="media[]" type="file">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Select File</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="input-file uniform_on" id="media[]" name="media[]" type="file">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Select File</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="input-file uniform_on" id="media[]" name="media[]" type="file">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Select File</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="input-file uniform_on" id="media[]" name="media[]" type="file">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--<input type="text" class="span6 typeahead" id="city" name="city"    required >
        <p class="help-block">Example : Nalasopara , Vasai road ..</p>-->

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    //$media=$_POST["media"];
    //$media=$_FILES['media']['name'];
    $type="";
    $count=count($_POST["media"]);
    //echo "count: ".$count."<br>";

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $media1=$media[$i];
        if($media1=="")
        {
        }
        else
        {
            $ext = pathinfo($media1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if($ext=="jpg"||$ext=="JPEG"||$ext=="JPG"||$ext=="png"||$ext=="gif"||$ext=="GIF")
            {
                $type="image";
                //echo $type;
            }
            else if($ext=="flv"||$ext=="mp4"||$ext=="wma"||$ext=="3gp"||$ext=="mpeg"||$ext=="mkv"||$ext=="avi")
            {
                $type="video";
            }

            $filename = ("gallery");

            if (file_exists($filename))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media"]["tmp_name"][$i], "$filename/".$_FILES["media"]["name"][$i]);
            }
            else
            {
                mkdir("gallery");
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media"]["tmp_name"][$i], "$filename/".$_FILES["media"]["name"][$i]);
            }
        }
    }
    //header('Location: gallery.php');
}
?>
```

folder is getting created but files are not getting uploaded,kindly help.

Comment: Set the correct encoding type on the form, then use the `$_FILES` array: `<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="gallery.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 1):

Add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="gallery.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

**Edit:**

```
$filename = "gallery";

if (is_dir($filename))
{
    $filename .= "/" . $_FILES["media"]["name"][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media"]["tmp_name"][$i], $filename);
}
else
{
    if(mkdir($filename))
    {
        $filename .= "/" . $_FILES["media"]["name"][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media"]["tmp_name"][$i], $filename);
    }

}
```

Comment: but still I am unable to upload the file :(

Comment: is it correct to use it as:
$filename/".$_FILES["media"]["name"][$i]

Comment: instead of uploading single file each time, use `multiple` attribute. `<input class="input-file uniform_on" id="media" name="media" type="file" multiple>`

Comment: @DineshSuthar see upadated answer

Comment: according to your code,gallery folder is getting created but files are still not  uploaded in it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="gallery.php" enctype='multipart/form-data>
```

Also check  `$filename = ("gallery");`.. seems to be wrong value assign to `$filename`

Comment: gallery is the folder in which the uploaded files will go.

Comment: Right , but it should be like $filename = "gallery"; and also check cross check your path  [ server path where gallery directory is located ]

Comment: Check folder permission for gallery folder ..it should be 755